# Challenge value not responding when connecting to request URL using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, slack, slack-api

I am trying to connect to my request URL in slack but it does not respond with the challenge value like it is supposed to. This has never been an issue before and I have not changed the code so i'm very confused why I have this. There is no message in the ngrok terminal either or the python code terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is entirely possible the reason this is happening to you is because the events request URL you are using is following http rather than https.

The Slack events API documentation (https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api) lists failure conditions, which include the statement:

> We consider any of these scenarios a single failure condition:
>
> - we are unable to negotiate or validate your server's SSL certificate

No SSL certificate would be present with an http connection, so the solution for you may be **to use an https url for your endpoint (which, in your case, should be provided by ngrok alongside the http url they give you).**

As to why the previous request URL shows as verified (or why http may work some of the time), this is a problem I have run into myself. In my experience, it sometimes happens when I use the App Manifest feature, or when I set the app's distribution to public (which would enforce https for all endpoints).